# How to duplicate my C# executable whilst bundling a text file as perhaps a resource?

Tags: c#, resources, exe

My c# program is a programming language interpreter, the base executable works fine. But I'm trying to make a "bundler" command which will bundle a text file (as perhaps a resource file or something) along with the interpreter executable. So when the bundled exe is ran, it will detect that there is a bundled resource file and execute that.

This would be similar to how nexe works with Node.JS.

If it's possible, this should be done entirely in C# so the interpreter executable can directly create a bundle.

I've tried using Mono.Cecil:

```
var module = Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("z.exe");

var file = new EmbeddedResource(
    "program.zr",
    Mono.Cecil.ManifestResourceAttributes.Public,
    File.ReadAllBytes("a.zr")
    );

module.MainModule.Resources.Add(file);
module.Write("c.exe");
```

However, this gives me `System.BadImageFormatException: 'Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.'`

I've tried to publish it as a single exe, x86 and x64 but the same error still occurs.
I've tried searching everywhere but can't find a thing that works.

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error? In the code you posted (on which line?) or when trying to execute c.exe?

Comment: @KlausGütter sorry, the error is on the first line of the code block